# Google Search Appliance: Using entity recognition in tandem with document dates

Tags: google-search-appliance

Is it possible to use a defined entity as a document date for sorting?

I have created an entity which successfully shows up in dynamic navigation and also responds to the search:

```
inmeta:gsaentity_pubdate
```

I have entered a host pattern in the document dates section with a `Locate Date In` of `Meta Tag`, and `Meta Tag Name` of `gsaentity_pubdate`.

When checking the resulting search XML with `sort=D:S:d1` or `sort=D:L:d1`, the results come back with no date:

```
<FS NAME="date" VALUE=""/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that it is not possible to use entity recognition-generated metadata in certain areas of the GSA as of firmware 7.0.

The `getfields=` parameter does not return `gsaentity_` metadata fields in the results (**except** when using `getfields=*`, see Michael's comment); it only selects actual metadata fields from the original document.  This indicates that there is a logical separation between these two types of metadata in the GSA, and type 2 metadata generated by entity recognition cannot be used in many places where type 1 metadata can.

Comment: The getfields parameter does return entity fields when you do something like getfields=*.  I created a source parameter recently and it comes out as normal metadata in the interface:

    <MT N="description" V=""/>
    <MT N="viewport" V="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <MT N="generator" V="WordPress 3.5.1"/>
    <MT N="syntaxhighlighter-version" V="3.1.5"/>
    <MT N="gsaentity_Source" V="Web"/>

which is literally what comes out of my GSA.  Have you checked the format?

Comment: Michael: that's very interesting.  `getfields=*` does seem to return everything.  However if I try `getfields=gsaentity_Country` which did show up when using `getfields=*`, I get nothing at all.  I still believe this answer is correct because the "type 2" metadata I mentioned can't be retrieved by name.  Good to know, though.